# Retrieve all child/descendant/related entities programmatically

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, entities

How do I retrieve all of the related entities of a source entity in CRM Dynamics 2011, in C#?

thanks

Comment: It took 10 seconds to find this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334607.aspx. There is explained how to retrieve records using c#. Also your environment is not clear. Synchronous plug-in, asynchronous workflow plug-in, an external application? Do you already have code?

Comment: Hi, I already know how to retrieve data. I want to know how to retrieve related entities of an entity. It seems like there should be an easy way to do that but I can't seem to find it

Comment: Do you use FetchXml based queries, QueryExpressions or LINQ to retrieve records?

Comment: I prefer fetchxml but any will do.

Answer (score 1):

FetchXml is overkill for this requirement, but obviously if you want to construct the FetchXml and use it for your `QueryBase` in place of the `QueryExpression` I'm showing you are free to do that. The logic remains the same.

```
//Assumes you have a Entity() object of the parent entity
//somehow you have to know the parent entity record's Id

Guid parentId = parentEntity.Id;
var query = new QueryExpression("new_childentity");
query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("new_lookupfield", ConditionOperator.Equal, parentId));
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
var results = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
if (results.Entities.Any())
{
     //Do your processing here
}
else
{
     //Do whatever when there are no child entities
}
```